# Mac install PocketSphinx dependencies missing

Tags: macos, pocketsphinx

I successfully installed PocketSphinx on Ubuntu16.04 and Mac 10.13.6(High Sierra), When I tried to install it on Mac 10.14.5(Mojave) with the command: `$ pip3 install pocketsphinx`, it couldn't find `swig`.

and got this error

```
Collecting pocketsphinx
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/cd/4a/adea55f189a81aed88efa0b0e1d25628e5ed22622ab9174bf696dd4f9474/pocketsphinx-0.1.15.tar.gz
Building wheels for collected packages: pocketsphinx
  Building wheel for pocketsphinx (setup.py) ... error
  ERROR: Complete output from command /Users/lzl/anaconda3/bin/python -u -c 'import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='"'"'/private/var/folders/gg/85tn8f210s59lz087b_ftc8m0000gn/T/pip-install-yiu5l4t9/pocketsphinx/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' bdist_wheel -d /private/var/folders/gg/85tn8f210s59lz087b_ftc8m0000gn/T/pip-wheel-h2va4b_y --python-tag cp37:
  ERROR: running bdist_wheel
  running build_ext
  building 'sphinxbase._sphinxbase' extension
  swigging deps/sphinxbase/swig/sphinxbase.i to deps/sphinxbase/swig/sphinxbase_wrap.c
  swig -python -modern -threads -Ideps/sphinxbase/include -Ideps/sphinxbase/include/sphinxbase -Ideps/sphinxbase/include/android -Ideps/sphinxbase/swig -outdir sphinxbase -o deps/sphinxbase/swig/sphinxbase_wrap.c deps/sphinxbase/swig/sphinxbase.i
  unable to execute 'swig': No such file or directory
  error: command 'swig' failed with exit status 1
  ----------------------------------------
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for pocketsphinx
```

I thought maybe I need swig so I installed swig separately but still got another error

```
ERROR: Complete output from command /Users/lzl/anaconda3/bin/python -u -c 'import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='"'"'/private/var/folders/gg/85tn8f210s59lz087b_ftc8m0000gn/T/pip-install-6cx6cog5/pocketsphinx/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /private/var/folders/gg/85tn8f210s59lz087b_ftc8m0000gn/T/pip-record-vn4e3pmx/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile:
    ERROR: running install
    running build_ext
    building 'sphinxbase._sphinxbase' extension
    swigging deps/sphinxbase/swig/sphinxbase.i to deps/sphinxbase/swig/sphinxbase_wrap.c
    swig -python -modern -threads -Ideps/sphinxbase/include -Ideps/sphinxbase/include/sphinxbase -Ideps/sphinxbase/include/android -Ideps/sphinxbase/swig -outdir sphinxbase -o deps/sphinxbase/swig/sphinxbase_wrap.c deps/sphinxbase/swig/sphinxbase.i
    Deprecated command line option: -modern. This option is now always on.
    creating build
    creating build/temp.macosx-10.7-x86_64-3.7
    creating build/temp.macosx-10.7-x86_64-3.7/deps
    creating build/temp.macosx-10.7-x86_64-3.7/deps/sphinxbase
    creating build/temp.macosx-10.7-x86_64-3.7/deps/sphinxbase/src
    creating build/temp.macosx-10.7-x86_64-3.7/deps/sphinxbase/src/libsphinxbase
    creating build/temp.macosx-10.7-x86_64-3.7/deps/sphinxbase/src/libsphinxbase/lm
    creating build/temp.macosx-10.7-x86_64-3.7/deps/sphinxbase/src/libsphinxbase/feat
    creating build/temp.macosx-10.7-x86_64-3.7/deps/sphinxbase/src/libsphinxbase/util
    creating build/temp.macosx-10.7-x86_64-3.7/deps/sphinxbase/src/libsphinxbase/fe
    creating build/temp.macosx-10.7-x86_64-3.7/deps/sphinxbase/swig
    gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -I/Users/lzl/anaconda3/include -arch x86_64 -I/Users/lzl/anaconda3/include -arch x86_64 -DSPHINXBASE_EXPORTS -DPOCKETSPHINX_EXPORTS -DSPHINX_DLL -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -Ideps/sphinxbase/include -Ideps/sphinxbase/include/sphinxbase -Ideps/sphinxbase/include/android -I/System/Library/Frameworks/OpenAL.framework/Versions/A/Headers -I/Users/lzl/anaconda3/include/python3.7m -c deps/sphinxbase/src/libsphinxbase/lm/ngram_model_set.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.7-x86_64-3.7/deps/sphinxbase/src/libsphinxbase/lm/ngram_model_set.o -Wno-macro-redefined -Wno-sign-compare -Wno-logical-op-parentheses
    gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -I/Users/lzl/anaconda3/include -arch x86_64 -I/Users/lzl/anaconda3/include -arch x86_64 -DSPHINXBASE_EXPORTS -DPOCKETSPHINX_EXPORTS -DSPHINX_DLL -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -Ideps/sphinxbase/include -Ideps/sphinxbase/include/sphinxbase -Ideps/sphinxbase/include/android -I/System/Library/Frameworks/OpenAL.framework/Versions/A/Headers -I/Users/lzl/anaconda3/include/python3.7m -c deps/sphinxbase/src/libsphinxbase/lm/jsgf.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.7-x86_64-3.7/deps/sphinxbase/src/libsphinxbase/lm/jsgf.o -Wno-macro-redefined -Wno-sign-compare -Wno-logical-op-parentheses
    gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -I/Users/lzl/anaconda3/include -arch x86_64 -I/Users/lzl/anaconda3/include -arch x86_64 -DSPHINXBASE_EXPORTS -DPOCKETSPHINX_EXPORTS -DSPHINX_DLL -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -Ideps/sphinxbase/include -Ideps/sphinxbase/include/sphinxbase -Ideps/sphinxbase/include/android -I/System/Library/Frameworks/OpenAL.framework/Versions/A/Headers -I/Users/lzl/anaconda3/include/python3.7m -c deps/sphinxbase/src/libsphinxbase/lm/ngram_model.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.7-x86_64-3.7/deps/sphinxbase/src/libsphinxbase/lm/ngram_model.o -Wno-macro-redefined -Wno-sign-compare -Wno-logical-op-parentheses

1 warning generated.
    gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -I/Users/lzl/anaconda3/include -arch x86_64 -I/Users/lzl/anaconda3/include -arch x86_64 -DSPHINXBASE_EXPORTS -DPOCKETSPHINX_EXPORTS -DSPHINX_DLL -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -Ideps/sphinxbase/include -Ideps/sphinxbase/include/sphinxbase -Ideps/sphinxbase/include/android -I/System/Library/Frameworks/OpenAL.framework/Versions/A/Headers -I/Users/lzl/anaconda3/include/python3.7m -c deps/sphinxbase/src/libsphinxbase/lm/jsgf_parser.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.7-x86_64-3.7/deps/sphinxbase/src/libsphinxbase/lm/jsgf_parser.o -Wno-macro-redefined -Wno-sign-compare -Wno-logical-op-parentheses
    jsgf_parser.c:1685:6: warning: code will never be executed [-Wunreachable-code]
         goto yyerrorlab;
         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    jsgf_parser.c:1684:21: note: silence by adding parentheses to mark code as explicitly dead
      if (/*CONSTCOND*/ 0)
                        ^
                        /* DISABLES CODE */ ( )
    1 warning generated.
    gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -I/Users/lzl/anaconda3/include -arch x86_64 -I/Users/lzl/anaconda3/include -arch x86_64 -DSPHINXBASE_EXPORTS -DPOCKETSPHINX_EXPORTS -DSPHINX_DLL -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -Ideps/sphinxbase/include -Ideps/sphinxbase/include/sphinxbase -Ideps/sphinxbase/include/android -I/System/Library/Frameworks/OpenAL.framework/Versions/A/Headers -I/Users/lzl/anaconda3/include/python3.7m -c deps/sphinxbase/src/libsphinxbase/lm/fsg_model.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.7-x86_64-3.7/deps/sphinxbase/src/libsphinxbase/lm/fsg_model.o -Wno-macro-redefined -Wno-sign-compare -Wno-logical-op-parentheses

gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -I/Users/lzl/anaconda3/include -arch x86_64 -I/Users/lzl/anaconda3/include -arch x86_64 -DSPHINXBASE_EXPORTS -DPOCKETSPHINX_EXPORTS -DSPHINX_DLL -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -Ideps/sphinxbase/include -Ideps/sphinxbase/include/sphinxbase -Ideps/sphinxbase/include/android -I/System/Library/Frameworks/OpenAL.framework/Versions/A/Headers -I/Users/lzl/anaconda3/include/python3.7m -c deps/sphinxbase/swig/sphinxbase_wrap.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.7-x86_64-3.7/deps/sphinxbase/swig/sphinxbase_wrap.o -Wno-macro-redefined -Wno-sign-compare -Wno-logical-op-parentheses
    creating build/lib.macosx-10.7-x86_64-3.7
    creating build/lib.macosx-10.7-x86_64-3.7/sphinxbase
    gcc -bundle -undefined dynamic_lookup -L/Users/lzl/anaconda3/lib -arch x86_64 -L/Users/lzl/anaconda3/lib -arch x86_64 -arch x86_64 build/temp.macosx-10.7-x86_64-3.7/deps/sphinxbase/src/libsphinxbase/lm/ngram_model_set.o build/temp.macosx-10.7-x86_64-3.7/deps/sphinxbase/src/libsphinxbase/lm/jsgf.o build/temp.macosx-10.7-x86_64-3.7/deps/sphinxbase/src/libsphinxbase/lm/ngram_model.o build/temp.macosx-10.7-x86_64-3.7/deps/sphinxbase/src/libsphinxbase/lm/lm_trie.o build/temp.macosx-10.7-x86_64-3.7/deps/sphinxbase/src/libsphinxbase/lm/ngrams_raw.o build/temp.macosx-10.7-x86_64-3.7/deps/sphinxbase/src/libsphinxbase/lm/lm_trie_quant.o build/temp.macosx-10.7-x86_64-3.7/deps/sphinxbase/src/libsphinxbase/lm/ngram_model_trie.o build/temp.macosx-10.7-x86_64-3.7/deps/sphinxbase/src/libsphinxbase/lm/jsgf_scanner.o build/temp.macosx-10.7-x86_64-3.7/deps/sphinxbase/src/libsphinxbase/lm/jsgf_parser.o build/temp.macosx-10.7-x86_64-3.7/deps/sphinxbase/src/libsphinxbase/lm/fsg_model.o build/temp.macosx-10.7-x86_64-3.7/deps/sphinxbase/src/libsphinxbase/feat/agc.o build/temp.macosx-10.7-x86_64-3.7/deps/sphinxbase/src/libsphinxbase/feat/cmn.o build/temp.macosx-10.7-x86_64-3.7/deps/sphinxbase/src/libsphinxbase/feat/cmn_live.o build/temp.macosx-10.7-x86_64-3.7/deps/sphinxbase/src/libsphinxbase/feat/lda.o build/temp.macosx-10.7-x86_64-3.7/deps/sphinxbase/src/libsphinxbase/feat/feat.o build/temp.macosx-10.7-x86_64-3.7/deps/sphinxbase/src/libsphinxbase/util/strfuncs.o build/temp.macosx-10.7-x86_64-3.7/deps/sphinxbase/src/libsphinxbase/util/slamch.o build/temp.macosx-10.7-x86_64-3.7/deps/sphinxbase/src/libsphinxbase/util/dtoa.o build/temp.macosx-10.7-x86_64-3.7/deps/sphinxbase/src/libsphinxbase/util/heap.o build/temp.macosx-10.7-x86_64-3.7/deps/sphinxbase/src/libsphinxbase/util/cmd_ln.o build/temp.macosx-10.7-x86_64-3.7/deps/sphinxbase/src/libsphinxbase/util/bitarr.o build/temp.macosx-10.7-x86_64-3.7/deps/sphinxbase/src/libsphinxbase/util/filename.o build/temp.macosx-10.7-x86_64-3.7/deps/sphinxbase/src/libsphinxbase/util/bitvec.o build/temp.macosx-10.7-x86_64-3.7/deps/sphinxbase/src/libsphinxbase/util/case.o build/temp.macosx-10.7-x86_64-3.7/deps/sphinxbase/src/libsphinxbase/util/errno.o build/temp.macosx-10.7-x86_64-3.7/deps/sphinxbase/src/libsphinxbase/util/ckd_alloc.o build/temp.macosx-10.7-x86_64-3.7/deps/sphinxbase/src/libsphinxbase/util/logmath.o build/temp.macosx-10.7-x86_64-3.7/deps/sphinxbase/src/libsphinxbase/util/sbthread.o build/temp.macosx-10.7-x86_64-3.7/deps/sphinxbase/src/libsphinxbase/util/glist.o build/temp.macosx-10.7-x86_64-3.7/deps/sphinxbase/src/libsphinxbase/util/pio.o build/temp.macosx-10.7-x86_64-3.7/deps/sphinxbase/src/libsphinxbase/util/err.o build/temp.macosx-10.7-x86_64-3.7/deps/sphinxbase/src/libsphinxbase/util/slapack_lite.o build/temp.macosx-10.7-x86_64-3.7/deps/sphinxbase/src/libsphinxbase/util/bio.o build/temp.macosx-10.7-x86_64-3.7/deps/sphinxbase/src/libsphinxbase/util/listelem_alloc.o build/temp.macosx-10.7-x86_64-3.7/deps/sphinxbase/src/libsphinxbase/util/mmio.o build/temp.macosx-10.7-x86_64-3.7/deps/sphinxbase/src/libsphinxbase/util/profile.o build/temp.macosx-10.7-x86_64-3.7/deps/sphinxbase/src/libsphinxbase/util/genrand.o build/temp.macosx-10.7-x86_64-3.7/deps/sphinxbase/src/libsphinxbase/util/hash_table.o build/temp.macosx-10.7-x86_64-3.7/deps/sphinxbase/src/libsphinxbase/util/f2c_lite.o build/temp.macosx-10.7-x86_64-3.7/deps/sphinxbase/src/libsphinxbase/util/priority_queue.o build/temp.macosx-10.7-x86_64-3.7/deps/sphinxbase/src/libsphinxbase/util/blas_lite.o build/temp.macosx-10.7-x86_64-3.7/deps/sphinxbase/src/libsphinxbase/util/matrix.o build/temp.macosx-10.7-x86_64-3.7/deps/sphinxbase/src/libsphinxbase/fe/fe_interface.o build/temp.macosx-10.7-x86_64-3.7/deps/sphinxbase/src/libsphinxbase/fe/fe_warp.o build/temp.macosx-10.7-x86_64-3.7/deps/sphinxbase/src/libsphinxbase/fe/fe_warp_inverse_linear.o build/temp.macosx-10.7-x86_64-3.7/deps/sphinxbase/src/libsphinxbase/fe/fe_sigproc.o build/temp.macosx-10.7-x86_64-3.7/deps/sphinxbase/src/libsphinxbase/fe/fe_prespch_buf.o build/temp.macosx-10.7-x86_64-3.7/deps/sphinxbase/src/libsphinxbase/fe/fixlog.o build/temp.macosx-10.7-x86_64-3.7/deps/sphinxbase/src/libsphinxbase/fe/fe_warp_affine.o build/temp.macosx-10.7-x86_64-3.7/deps/sphinxbase/src/libsphinxbase/fe/yin.o build/temp.macosx-10.7-x86_64-3.7/deps/sphinxbase/src/libsphinxbase/fe/fe_noise.o build/temp.macosx-10.7-x86_64-3.7/deps/sphinxbase/src/libsphinxbase/fe/fe_warp_piecewise_linear.o build/temp.macosx-10.7-x86_64-3.7/deps/sphinxbase/swig/sphinxbase_wrap.o -o build/lib.macosx-10.7-x86_64-3.7/sphinxbase/_sphinxbase.cpython-37m-darwin.so
    building 'pocketsphinx._pocketsphinx' extension
    swigging deps/pocketsphinx/swig/pocketsphinx.i to deps/pocketsphinx/swig/pocketsphinx_wrap.c
    swig -python -modern -threads -Ideps/sphinxbase/include -Ideps/sphinxbase/include/sphinxbase -Ideps/sphinxbase/include/android -Ideps/pocketsphinx/include -Ideps/sphinxbase/swig -outdir pocketsphinx -o deps/pocketsphinx/swig/pocketsphinx_wrap.c deps/pocketsphinx/swig/pocketsphinx.i
    Deprecated command line option: -modern. This option is now always on.
    creating build/temp.macosx-10.7-x86_64-3.7/deps/pocketsphinx
    creating build/temp.macosx-10.7-x86_64-3.7/deps/pocketsphinx/src
    creating build/temp.macosx-10.7-x86_64-3.7/deps/pocketsphinx/src/libpocketsphinx
    creating build/temp.macosx-10.7-x86_64-3.7/deps/pocketsphinx/swig
    gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -I/Users/lzl/anaconda3/include -arch x86_64 -I/Users/lzl/anaconda3/include -arch x86_64 -DSPHINXBASE_EXPORTS -DPOCKETSPHINX_EXPORTS -DSPHINX_DLL -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -Ideps/sphinxbase/include -Ideps/sphinxbase/include/sphinxbase -Ideps/sphinxbase/include/android -Ideps/pocketsphinx/include -I/Users/lzl/anaconda3/include/python3.7m -c deps/sphinxbase/src/libsphinxbase/lm/ngram_model_set.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.7-x86_64-3.7/deps/sphinxbase/src/libsphinxbase/lm/ngram_model_set.o -Wno-macro-redefined -Wno-sign-compare -Wno-logical-op-parentheses
    gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -I/Users/lzl/anaconda3/include -arch x86_64 -I/Users/lzl/anaconda3/include -arch x86_64 -DSPHINXBASE_EXPORTS -DPOCKETSPHINX_EXPORTS -DSPHINX_DLL -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -Ideps/sphinxbase/include -Ideps/sphinxbase/include/sphinxbase -Ideps/sphinxbase/include/android -Ideps/pocketsphinx/include -I/Users/lzl/anaconda3/include/python3.7m -c deps/sphinxbase/src/libsphinxbase/lm/jsgf.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.7-x86_64-3.7/deps/sphinxbase/src/libsphinxbase/lm/jsgf.o -Wno-macro-redefined -Wno-sign-compare -Wno-logical-op-parentheses
    gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -I/Users/lzl/anaconda3/include -arch x86_64 -I/Users/lzl/anaconda3/include -arch x86_64 -DSPHINXBASE_EXPORTS -DPOCKETSPHINX_EXPORTS -DSPHINX_DLL -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -Ideps/sphinxbase/include -Ideps/sphinxbase/include/sphinxbase -Ideps/sphinxbase/include/android -Ideps/pocketsphinx/include -I/Users/lzl/anaconda3/include/python3.7m -c deps/sphinxbase/src/libsphinxbase/lm/ngram_model.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.7-x86_64-3.7/deps/sphinxbase/src/libsphinxbase/lm/ngram_model.o -Wno-macro-redefined -Wno-sign-compare -Wno-logical-op-parentheses
    gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -I/Users/lzl/anaconda3/include -arch x86_64 -I/Users/lzl/anaconda3/include -arch x86_64 -DSPHINXBASE_EXPORTS -DPOCKETSPHINX_EXPORTS -DSPHINX_DLL -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -Ideps/sphinxbase/include -Ideps/sphinxbase/include/sphinxbase -Ideps/sphinxbase/include/android -Ideps/pocketsphinx/include -I/Users/lzl/anaconda3/include/python3.7m -c deps/sphinxbase/src/libsphinxbase/lm/lm_trie.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.7-x86_64-3.7/deps/sphinxbase/src/libsphinxbase/lm/lm_trie.o -Wno-macro-redefined -Wno-sign-compare -Wno-logical-op-parentheses

gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -I/Users/lzl/anaconda3/include -arch x86_64 -I/Users/lzl/anaconda3/include -arch x86_64 -DSPHINXBASE_EXPORTS -DPOCKETSPHINX_EXPORTS -DSPHINX_DLL -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -Ideps/sphinxbase/include -Ideps/sphinxbase/include/sphinxbase -Ideps/sphinxbase/include/android -Ideps/pocketsphinx/include -I/Users/lzl/anaconda3/include/python3.7m -c deps/sphinxbase/src/libsphinxbase/lm/jsgf_scanner.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.7-x86_64-3.7/deps/sphinxbase/src/libsphinxbase/lm/jsgf_scanner.o -Wno-macro-redefined -Wno-sign-compare -Wno-logical-op-parentheses
    jsgf_scanner.c:1165:13: warning: code will never be executed [-Wunreachable-code]
                                            if ( ! yyg->yy_did_buffer_switch_on_eof )
                                                   ^~~
    1 warning generated.
    gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -I/Users/lzl/anaconda3/include -arch x86_64 -I/Users/lzl/anaconda3/include -arch x86_64 -DSPHINXBASE_EXPORTS -DPOCKETSPHINX_EXPORTS -DSPHINX_DLL -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -Ideps/sphinxbase/include -Ideps/sphinxbase/include/sphinxbase -Ideps/sphinxbase/include/android -Ideps/pocketsphinx/include -I/Users/lzl/anaconda3/include/python3.7m -c deps/sphinxbase/src/libsphinxbase/lm/jsgf_parser.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.7-x86_64-3.7/deps/sphinxbase/src/libsphinxbase/lm/jsgf_parser.o -Wno-macro-redefined -Wno-sign-compare -Wno-logical-op-parentheses
    jsgf_parser.c:1685:6: warning: code will never be executed [-Wunreachable-code]
         goto yyerrorlab;
         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    jsgf_parser.c:1684:21: note: silence by adding parentheses to mark code as explicitly dead
      if (/*CONSTCOND*/ 0)
                        ^
                        /* DISABLES CODE */ ( )
    1 warning generated.
    gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -I/Users/lzl/anaconda3/include -arch x86_64 -I/Users/lzl/anaconda3/include -arch x86_64 -DSPHINXBASE_EXPORTS -DPOCKETSPHINX_EXPORTS -DSPHINX_DLL -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -Ideps/sphinxbase/include -Ideps/sphinxbase/include/sphinxbase -Ideps/sphinxbase/include/android -Ideps/pocketsphinx/include -I/Users/lzl/anaconda3/include/python3.7m -c deps/sphinxbase/src/libsphinxbase/lm/fsg_model.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.7-x86_64-3.7/deps/sphinxbase/src/libsphinxbase/lm/fsg_model.o -Wno-macro-redefined -Wno-sign-compare -Wno-logical-op-parentheses
    gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -I/Users/lzl/anaconda3/include -arch x86_64 -I/Users/lzl/anaconda3/include -arch x86_64 -DSPHINXBASE_EXPORTS -DPOCKETSPHINX_EXPORTS -DSPHINX_DLL -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -Ideps/sphinxbase/include -Ideps/sphinxbase/include/sphinxbase -Ideps/sphinxbase/include/android -Ideps/pocketsphinx/include -I/Users/lzl/anaconda3/include/python3.7m -c deps/sphinxbase/src/libsphinxbase/feat/agc.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.7-x86_64-3.7/deps/sphinxbase/src/libsphinxbase/feat/agc.o -Wno-macro-redefined -Wno-sign-compare -Wno-logical-op-parentheses

gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -I/Users/lzl/anaconda3/include -arch x86_64 -I/Users/lzl/anaconda3/include -arch x86_64 -DSPHINXBASE_EXPORTS -DPOCKETSPHINX_EXPORTS -DSPHINX_DLL -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -Ideps/sphinxbase/include -Ideps/sphinxbase/include/sphinxbase -Ideps/sphinxbase/include/android -Ideps/pocketsphinx/include -I/Users/lzl/anaconda3/include/python3.7m -c deps/pocketsphinx/swig/pocketsphinx_wrap.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.7-x86_64-3.7/deps/pocketsphinx/swig/pocketsphinx_wrap.o -Wno-macro-redefined -Wno-sign-compare -Wno-logical-op-parentheses
    creating build/lib.macosx-10.7-x86_64-3.7/pocketsphinx
    gcc -bundle -undefined dynamic_lookup -L/Users/lzl/anaconda3/lib -arch x86_64 -L/Users/lzl/anaconda3/lib -arch x86_64 -arch x86_64 build/temp.macosx-10.7-x86_64-3.7/deps/sphinxbase/src/libsphinxbase/lm/ngram_model_set.o build/temp.macosx-10.7-x86_64-3.7/deps/sphinxbase/src/libsphinxbase/lm/jsgf.o build/temp.macosx-10.7-x86_64-3.7/deps/sphinxbase/src/libsphinxbase/lm/ngram_model.o build/temp.macosx-10.7-x86_64-3.7/deps/sphinxbase/src/libsphinxbase/lm/lm_trie.o build/temp.macosx-10.7-x86_64-3.7/deps/sphinxbase/src/libsphinxbase/lm/ngrams_raw.o build/temp.macosx-10.7-x86_64-3.7/deps/sphinxbase/src/libsphinxbase/lm/lm_trie_quant.o build/temp.macosx-10.7-x86_64-3.7/deps/sphinxbase/src/libsphinxbase/lm/ngram_model_trie.o build/temp.macosx-10.7-x86_64-3.7/deps/sphinxbase/src/libsphinxbase/lm/jsgf_scanner.o build/temp.macosx-10.7-x86_64-3.7/deps/sphinxbase/src/libsphinxbase/lm/jsgf_parser.o build/temp.macosx-10.7-x86_64-3.7/deps/sphinxbase/src/libsphinxbase/lm/fsg_model.o build/temp.macosx-10.7-x86_64-3.7/deps/sphinxbase/src/libsphinxbase/feat/agc.o build/temp.macosx-10.7-x86_64-3.7/deps/sphinxbase/src/libsphinxbase/feat/cmn.o build/temp.macosx-10.7-x86_64-3.7/deps/sphinxbase/src/libsphinxbase/feat/cmn_live.o build/temp.macosx-10.7-x86_64-3.7/deps/sphinxbase/src/libsphinxbase/feat/lda.o build/temp.macosx-10.7-x86_64-3.7/deps/sphinxbase/src/libsphinxbase/feat/feat.o build/temp.macosx-10.7-x86_64-3.7/deps/sphinxbase/src/libsphinxbase/util/strfuncs.o build/temp.macosx-10.7-x86_64-3.7/deps/sphinxbase/src/libsphinxbase/util/slamch.o build/temp.macosx-10.7-x86_64-3.7/deps/sphinxbase/src/libsphinxbase/util/dtoa.o build/temp.macosx-10.7-x86_64-3.7/deps/sphinxbase/src/libsphinxbase/util/heap.o build/temp.macosx-10.7-x86_64-3.7/deps/sphinxbase/src/libsphinxbase/util/cmd_ln.o build/temp.macosx-10.7-x86_64-3.7/deps/sphinxbase/src/libsphinxbase/util/bitarr.o build/temp.macosx-10.7-x86_64-3.7/deps/sphinxbase/src/libsphinxbase/util/filename.o build/temp.macosx-10.7-x86_64-3.7/deps/sphinxbase/src/libsphinxbase/util/bitvec.o build/temp.macosx-10.7-x86_64-3.7/deps/sphinxbase/src/libsphinxbase/util/case.o build/temp.macosx-10.7-x86_64-3.7/deps/sphinxbase/src/libsphinxbase/util/errno.o build/temp.macosx-10.7-x86_64-3.7/deps/sphinxbase/src/libsphinxbase/util/ckd_alloc.o build/temp.macosx-10.7-x86_64-3.7/deps/sphinxbase/src/libsphinxbase/util/logmath.o build/temp.macosx-10.7-x86_64-3.7/deps/sphinxbase/src/libsphinxbase/util/sbthread.o build/temp.macosx-10.7-x86_64-3.7/deps/sphinxbase/src/libsphinxbase/util/glist.o build/temp.macosx-10.7-x86_64-3.7/deps/sphinxbase/src/libsphinxbase/util/pio.o build/temp.macosx-10.7-x86_64-3.7/deps/sphinxbase/src/libsphinxbase/util/err.o build/temp.macosx-10.7-x86_64-3.7/deps/sphinxbase/src/libsphinxbase/util/slapack_lite.o build/temp.macosx-10.7-x86_64-3.7/deps/sphinxbase/src/libsphinxbase/util/bio.o build/temp.macosx-10.7-x86_64-3.7/deps/sphinxbase/src/libsphinxbase/util/listelem_alloc.o build/temp.macosx-10.7-x86_64-3.7/deps/sphinxbase/src/libsphinxbase/util/mmio.o build/temp.macosx-10.7-x86_64-3.7/deps/sphinxbase/src/libsphinxbase/util/profile.o build/temp.macosx-10.7-x86_64-3.7/deps/sphinxbase/src/libsphinxbase/util/genrand.o build/temp.macosx-10.7-x86_64-3.7/deps/sphinxbase/src/libsphinxbase/util/hash_table.o build/temp.macosx-10.7-x86_64-3.7/deps/sphinxbase/src/libsphinxbase/util/f2c_lite.o build/temp.macosx-10.7-x86_64-3.7/deps/sphinxbase/src/libsphinxbase/util/priority_queue.o build/temp.macosx-10.7-x86_64-3.7/deps/sphinxbase/src/libsphinxbase/util/blas_lite.o build/temp.macosx-10.7-x86_64-3.7/deps/sphinxbase/src/libsphinxbase/util/matrix.o build/temp.macosx-10.7-x86_64-3.7/deps/sphinxbase/src/libsphinxbase/fe/fe_interface.o build/temp.macosx-10.7-x86_64-3.7/deps/sphinxbase/src/libsphinxbase/fe/fe_warp.o build/temp.macosx-10.7-x86_64-3.7/deps/sphinxbase/src/libsphinxbase/fe/fe_warp_inverse_linear.o build/temp.macosx-10.7-x86_64-3.7/deps/sphinxbase/src/libsphinxbase/fe/fe_sigproc.o build/temp.macosx-10.7-x86_64-3.7/deps/sphinxbase/src/libsphinxbase/fe/fe_prespch_buf.o build/temp.macosx-10.7-x86_64-3.7/deps/sphinxbase/src/libsphinxbase/fe/fixlog.o build/temp.macosx-10.7-x86_64-3.7/deps/sphinxbase/src/libsphinxbase/fe/fe_warp_affine.o build/temp.macosx-10.7-x86_64-3.7/deps/sphinxbase/src/libsphinxbase/fe/yin.o build/temp.macosx-10.7-x86_64-3.7/deps/sphinxbase/src/libsphinxbase/fe/fe_noise.o build/temp.macosx-10.7-x86_64-3.7/deps/sphinxbase/src/libsphinxbase/fe/fe_warp_piecewise_linear.o build/temp.macosx-10.7-x86_64-3.7/deps/pocketsphinx/src/libpocketsphinx/dict.o build/temp.macosx-10.7-x86_64-3.7/deps/pocketsphinx/src/libpocketsphinx/ngram_search.o build/temp.macosx-10.7-x86_64-3.7/deps/pocketsphinx/src/libpocketsphinx/ps_mllr.o build/temp.macosx-10.7-x86_64-3.7/deps/pocketsphinx/src/libpocketsphinx/ms_mgau.o build/temp.macosx-10.7-x86_64-3.7/deps/pocketsphinx/src/libpocketsphinx/state_align_search.o build/temp.macosx-10.7-x86_64-3.7/deps/pocketsphinx/src/libpocketsphinx/ps_alignment.o build/temp.macosx-10.7-x86_64-3.7/deps/pocketsphinx/src/libpocketsphinx/dict2pid.o build/temp.macosx-10.7-x86_64-3.7/deps/pocketsphinx/src/libpocketsphinx/ms_gauden.o build/temp.macosx-10.7-x86_64-3.7/deps/pocketsphinx/src/libpocketsphinx/pocketsphinx.o build/temp.macosx-10.7-x86_64-3.7/deps/pocketsphinx/src/libpocketsphinx/ngram_search_fwdtree.o build/temp.macosx-10.7-x86_64-3.7/deps/pocketsphinx/src/libpocketsphinx/ps_lattice.o build/temp.macosx-10.7-x86_64-3.7/deps/pocketsphinx/src/libpocketsphinx/tmat.o build/temp.macosx-10.7-x86_64-3.7/deps/pocketsphinx/src/libpocketsphinx/fsg_history.o build/temp.macosx-10.7-x86_64-3.7/deps/pocketsphinx/src/libpocketsphinx/vector.o build/temp.macosx-10.7-x86_64-3.7/deps/pocketsphinx/src/libpocketsphinx/phone_loop_search.o build/temp.macosx-10.7-x86_64-3.7/deps/pocketsphinx/src/libpocketsphinx/kws_detections.o build/temp.macosx-10.7-x86_64-3.7/deps/pocketsphinx/src/libpocketsphinx/blkarray_list.o build/temp.macosx-10.7-x86_64-3.7/deps/pocketsphinx/src/libpocketsphinx/fsg_search.o build/temp.macosx-10.7-x86_64-3.7/deps/pocketsphinx/src/libpocketsphinx/fsg_lextree.o build/temp.macosx-10.7-x86_64-3.7/deps/pocketsphinx/src/libpocketsphinx/allphone_search.o build/temp.macosx-10.7-x86_64-3.7/deps/pocketsphinx/src/libpocketsphinx/mdef.o build/temp.macosx-10.7-x86_64-3.7/deps/pocketsphinx/src/libpocketsphinx/ms_senone.o build/temp.macosx-10.7-x86_64-3.7/deps/pocketsphinx/src/libpocketsphinx/acmod.o build/temp.macosx-10.7-x86_64-3.7/deps/pocketsphinx/src/libpocketsphinx/ptm_mgau.o build/temp.macosx-10.7-x86_64-3.7/deps/pocketsphinx/src/libpocketsphinx/s2_semi_mgau.o build/temp.macosx-10.7-x86_64-3.7/deps/pocketsphinx/src/libpocketsphinx/hmm.o build/temp.macosx-10.7-x86_64-3.7/deps/pocketsphinx/src/libpocketsphinx/kws_search.o build/temp.macosx-10.7-x86_64-3.7/deps/pocketsphinx/src/libpocketsphinx/bin_mdef.o build/temp.macosx-10.7-x86_64-3.7/deps/pocketsphinx/src/libpocketsphinx/ngram_search_fwdflat.o build/temp.macosx-10.7-x86_64-3.7/deps/pocketsphinx/swig/pocketsphinx_wrap.o -o build/lib.macosx-10.7-x86_64-3.7/pocketsphinx/_pocketsphinx.cpython-37m-darwin.so
    building 'sphinxbase._ad_openal' extension
    swigging swig/sphinxbase/ad_openal.i to swig/sphinxbase/ad_openal_wrap.c
    swig -python -modern -threads -Ideps/sphinxbase/include -Ideps/sphinxbase/include/sphinxbase -Ideps/sphinxbase/include/android -Ideps/sphinxbase/swig -outdir sphinxbase -o swig/sphinxbase/ad_openal_wrap.c swig/sphinxbase/ad_openal.i
    Deprecated command line option: -modern. This option is now always on.
    creating build/temp.macosx-10.7-x86_64-3.7/swig
    creating build/temp.macosx-10.7-x86_64-3.7/swig/sphinxbase
    creating build/temp.macosx-10.7-x86_64-3.7/deps/sphinxbase/src/libsphinxad
    gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -I/Users/lzl/anaconda3/include -arch x86_64 -I/Users/lzl/anaconda3/include -arch x86_64 -DSPHINXBASE_EXPORTS -DPOCKETSPHINX_EXPORTS -DSPHINX_DLL -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -Ideps/sphinxbase/include -Ideps/sphinxbase/include/sphinxbase -Ideps/sphinxbase/include/android -I/System/Library/Frameworks/OpenAL.framework/Versions/A/Headers -I/Users/lzl/anaconda3/include/python3.7m -c deps/sphinxbase/src/libsphinxad/ad_openal.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.7-x86_64-3.7/deps/sphinxbase/src/libsphinxad/ad_openal.o -Wno-macro-redefined -Wno-sign-compare -Wno-logical-op-parentheses
    deps/sphinxbase/src/libsphinxad/ad_openal.c:43:10: fatal error: 'al.h' file not found
    #include <al.h>
             ^~~~~~
    1 error generated.
    error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command "/Users/lzl/anaconda3/bin/python -u -c 'import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='"'"'/private/var/folders/gg/85tn8f210s59lz087b_ftc8m0000gn/T/pip-install-6cx6cog5/pocketsphinx/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /private/var/folders/gg/85tn8f210s59lz087b_ftc8m0000gn/T/pip-record-vn4e3pmx/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in /private/var/folders/gg/85tn8f210s59lz087b_ftc8m0000gn/T/pip-install-6cx6cog5/pocketsphinx/
```

How can I fix this? Thanks.

Comment: Can you please post the full stack trace of the second error (after installing swig). Thank you !

Comment: sorry for the late reply, I just edited the question, the error information is so large that I can only post part of them, I guess the major part of these error information starts with `gcc -Wno-unused-result...`@reportgunner

Comment: In your error I can see `fatal error: 'al.h' file not found`.
Googling for that error brought me to [this topic](https://www.leadwerks.com/community/topic/10236-getting-message-that-alalh-cannot-be-found/). Can you try installing OpenAL and see if it helps ? The command for linux is `sudo apt-get install libopenal1:i386 libopenal1`, I can't help for macos, sorry.

Comment: @reportgunner Yes I think you're correct, it seems to be something wrong with `OpenAL`, I guess this [link](https://github.com/bambocher/pocketsphinx-python/issues/28) solved my problem although I haven't confirmed it yet, `#include <al.h>` needed to be replaced by `#include <OpenAL/al.h>`, Thanks for your help.